# Soap sharepoint envelope

Tags: sharepoint, soap, ksoap2

I try to construct a correct soap envelope used ksoap2 lib

```
...

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        request.addProperty("listName", "Tasks");
        request.addProperty("viewName", null);
        request.addProperty("query", null);
        request.addProperty("viewFields", null);
        request.addProperty("rowLimit", "30");
        request.addProperty("queryOptions", null);
        request.addProperty("webID",null);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        String authentication = android.util.Base64.encodeToString("Administrator:Password".getBytes(), android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP);
        List<HeaderProperty> headers = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

        try {
          headers.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authentication));
          androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope, headers);
            Log.d("D", androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
...
```

In debug mode I see this envelope:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <v:Header/>
       <v:Body>
          <GetListItems id="o0" c:root="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
             <listName i:type="d:string">Tasks</listName>
             <viewName i:null="true"/>
             <query i:null="true"/>
             <viewFields i:null="true"/>
             <rowLimit i:type="d:string">30</rowLimit>
             <queryOptions i:null="true"/>
             <webID i:null="true"/>
          </GetListItems>
       </v:Body>
    </v:Envelope>
```

Where is header data? Maybe its will be add in the call method? 
Its a correct envelope?
And I had the same mistakes from my previous post with authorization in server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Header data is sent in HTTP headers, not in SOAP body, that is why they call it headers. When you use "HTTP basic" authentication, an `Authorization` header is added. See an example from Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Example

Comment: you can use soapUI to test against, by mocking the sharepoint service.